# WHERE not returning the right result

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm cracking my head why the WHERE is not returning the right results
(it is not returning properly the < and > results)
could someone help please? Thank you!

```
SELECT 
    country_txt AS Country
    ,DATE_FROM_PARTS(iyear, imonth, iday) AS Date
    ,count(eventid) AS Number of events
    ,SUM(Col1-Col2) AS Number of men
    ,SUM(Col3) AS Numbe of women
    ,SUM(Col4) AS Number of kids
FROM xxx
WHERE iyear=('2022') AND Country in ('USA') AND eventid >= 10 AND (Col1-Col2) >= 8
GROUP BY Country, Date
ORDER BY Country ASC, Date ASC
;
```

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify what exactly do you need as a result and what in this case it is returning?

Comment: Without some sample input data, and some actual and expected results it's going to be extremely difficult to debug this

Comment: please provide table data, expected result data and current result data

Comment: Probably not the issue, but `WHERE iyear=('2022')` is better as `WHERE iyear=2022`, if I assume that iyear is an integer

Answer (score 1):

Where you've put 'AND eventid >= 10 AND (Col1-Col2) >= 8' in your conditions, are you looking for cases with ten or more events and eight or more men? If so, get rid of that and stick the below under the 'group by' line:

```
HAVING COUNT(eventid) >= 10 AND SUM(Col1-Col2) >= 8
```